# PHP - How to return a variable from a class method?

Tags: php

I don't understand the concept of getter and setter methods in PHP, pls help me out.

Let's say I have this class:

```
class something()
{
  public function test()
  {
    $bla = 10;
    return $var;
  }
}
```

How do I get the follwing code to work:

```
    $something->test();
    echo $bla;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Some controvercy in title and (`don't understand the concept of getter and setter methods in PHP`). Your question have nothing to do with getters or setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First this:

```
return $var;
```

should be:

```
return $bla;
```

and second, the second part is wrong and should be like this:

```
$something = new something();
$bla = $something->test();
echo $bla;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make `$bla` global for that to work, which is rarely a good idea.

You would be better off returning that variable, which you could then assign to what you wish when calling the object's method.